# using awk to search across a decimal range

Tags: awk

I hope this isn't too naive a question.  I have a set of files that have a bunch of semicolon-separated items, some of which are numbers.  Example would be the following:

```
A;B;4.564;C;D;E;5.698;F;G;H;7.893
```

and so on.

Among the files, the numbers might vary slightly, for example, the 5.698 in the example above might be 5.691, or 5.703, etc. in other files.  So, I set up a search range, say from 5.685 to 5.710.  The code is fine up until the awk one-liner that actually performs this search, but I am stuck there.  Here is the awk code:

```
awk -v low=$NUM3 -v high=$NUM2 '{if ($0 >= low && $0 <= high) {print "1"} else {print "0"} }'
```

I am importing bash variables into awk to represent the search range, and then setting up a simple search if there is a number between the low and high values.  I have also tried other variations:

```
awk -v low=$NUM3 -v high=$NUM2 'low<=$0 && $0<=high'
```

Any help would be appreciated, I searched previous questions but didn't come across this particular issue.  I am not an awk expert by any means, so thanks in advance.

Comment: What sort of output are you expecting from your input example?  Are you looking for all numbers in that range to be printed?

Comment: That would be nice (and outside my coding expertise!), but not necessary.  I was just intending to generate a presence/absence flag, so "1" or "0" so I can track which files have particular ranges.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$0` in your first one-liner means the whole line you're matching on, so it probably isn't doing what you want.  If you want to process each token separately, you'll have to set a character to separate on (looks like `;` in your example) and use an awk for loop like so:

```
awk -F\; '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { print $i }}'
```

Inside the loop you can check for numbers in your range like so:

```
awk -F\; -v low=$NUM3 -v high=$NUM2 '{n=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if ($i >= low && $i <= high) { n++; }} print n}'
```

With clearer formatting that looks like this:

```
awk -F\; -v low=$NUM3 -v high=$NUM2 '{n=0;
                                      for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
                                         if ($i >= low && $i <= high) { 
                                           n++; 
                                         }
                                      } 
                                      print n;}'
```

This will print the number of times it found something in the given range for each line.

Comment: I was intending to have the $0 return the whole line (as awk '{print $0}' returns the whole line), and I was hoping that this could be an quick search and wouldn't require a more intensive nested loop.  But, I will give your solution a try.

Comment: Okay, this works great, but now it would be helpful to modify the output to print the sum of those values, i.e., so there is only one returned value, which I did simply by piping your output to a new awk to sum the values.  I'm sure there's a more efficient way, but this works.

Comment: Do you want it to sum up the numbers themselves or the number of times they occur in a file?